# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent ORM hasManyThrough

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

In my laravel 5.2 web app I have the following three tables-

**users**

```
id
username
```

**profiles**

```
id
user_id
```

**profile_images**

```
id
profile_id
```

To outline my scenario- a user can have one profile (one-to-one) and a profile can have many profile images (one-to-many).  The models for these tables with the relevant relationship functions are-

**User.php**

```
public function profile_images(){
    $this->hasManyThrough('App\ProfileImage', 'App\Profile');
}
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}
```

**Profile.php**

```
 public function profile_images()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\ProfileImage');
}
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**ProfileImage.php**

```
    public function profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile');
}
```

**My Problem**
When I call profile_images() on the User model I only get the user data and only column names back for the profiles and profile_images.  No attributes/data are returned even though I have a profile (with matching user_id to my test case) and two profile_images with matching profile_id.

Can you help? I'm assuming it's a problem with my hasManyThrough usage.

Thanks

Comment: Can you run get method. Something like this. $user->profile_images()->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your hasManyThrough ralation are fine, but when you call `profile_images` method it returns QueryBuilder instance. To get Collection of  related models use `get` method

```
$images = $user->profile_images()->get();
```

or just use laravel's "magic"

```
$images = $user->profile_images;
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks-works now with $user->profile_images()->get();.  $user->profile_images; doesn't work but I believe that will be due to my table/column naming convention and therefore needing to define the keys used in hasManyThrough().  But I'm happy using get().